# Overall covariance of Mixture of Gaussian

Tags: gaussian, pr.probability

I have a Mixture of Gaussians to model an arbitrary distribution. I would like to model a distribution derived from this GMM with:

Mean = Weighted average mean of GMM means.

I am not sure about how to combine the co variances of  each clusters into one. Is there a standard way for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that what you're looking for is the [law of total covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance)?